# Bundling TypeScript 3 library project definitions in the best possible way

Tags: typescript, definition, bundling-and-minification

I don't know what is the best approach when I want to merge TypeScript definitions of my project into one file. There is a lot of examples but I would like to hear about the best approach.. Could you please send me maybe link to repository on which I can base on? I have in mind library project of course, as simple as possible but with more than 1 .ts file.

I would like to avoid this kind of imports in my code:

```
import {Foo} from "@myLibs/lib/dist/ITest1";
import {Bar} from "@myLibs/lib/dist/ITest2";
```

and have:

```
import {Bar, Foo} from "@myLibs/lib";
```

Maybe the problem is how I'm defining main and types in my library's package.json file:

```
  "main": "dist/lib.js",
  "types": "dist/lib.d.ts",
```

Comment: Why do you care? It's not really important to minify because these files should never go to a browser.

Comment: I'm have in mind bundling not mimifing.. And I care because I would like to avoid this kind of imports in my code:
import {Foo} from "@myLibs/lib/dist/ITest1";
import {Bar} from "@myLibs/lib/dist/ITest2";


and have:

import {Bar, Foo} from "@myLibs/lib";

Comment: But why is this important to you? This is not a dig, I'm just curious. The `.d` files are typically not for humans to read.